# Replacing Lighted Ceiling Fan w Fixed Light

Tags: light-fixture, ceiling-fan

I just replaced a lighted ceiling fan with a fixed light fixture. My wall has two switches, one that controlled the fan and another that controlled the light. At the ceiling junction box, there was an off white wire, a black wire, a red wire, and the ground. My light fixture had black, white, and a ground wire. I connected the black to black, white to off white and the ground to ground. I capped the red. The light works fine when I turn it on and off but the light is now controlled by the switch which previously controlled the fan. That tells me the black wire in the junction box powered the fan previously and now sends power to the new light fixture. My question is can I keep it this way or should I connect the black fixture wire to the red junction box wire?

Answer (score 3):

You explained it perfectly and yes, you can keep it that way or switch the black wire from the fixture to the red wire and cap the black. You would want the switch that's the easiest to find, in the dark, to control the light.

Comment: Thank you Jack!  I can now ensure my wife that I will not burn the house down. Very much appreciated!  And thanks for the quick reply.  Stay safe out there. Tim